i have old fckeditor, and why now are hyper links to .pdf files not working?
mt hyperlinks to .pdf files just  stopped workimg on my site.   Now these links to .pdf files take me to my homepage.   Please help if you can
So, i am wanting .pdf  links to open .pdf files again and not take me to my homepage.
